# clEnqueueReadBuffer is too slow

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu, data-transfer

I'm using OpenCL 1.2 (SDK from NVIDIA) to do some real-time raytracing. Now I faced the problem of very slow data transfer between GPU and CPU. The most concerned part is the transfer of the output data from GPU back to the host as it's performed each frame. I use clEnqueueReadBuffer to read the data. The buffer is created as a copy of host's data. It takes about 8ms to read 4*800*600 bytes (image dimensions, RGBA 32bit). That is not acceptable speed, how can I fix it ?

I also tried clEnqueueMapBuffer but still the same results.

**EDIT: added host code**

```
struct CL_Sphere
{
    rs::vec4 center,color,rad;
    CL_Sphere(vec3 c, float rad, vec3 cc):center((vec4)c), color((vec4)cc), rad(vec4(rad,0,0,0)){}
};

class CLLib
{
private:
    cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
    cl_context context = NULL;
    cl_command_queue command_queue = NULL;
    cl_program program = NULL;
    cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
    cl_uint ret_num_devices;
    cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
    cl_int ret;
    string source;

    cl_mem memobjInput = NULL;
    cl_mem memobjOutput = NULL;

    cl_kernel kernel = NULL;

    size_t workGroups;
    size_t workItems;
    size_t dimSize;


public:

    size_t inputSize;
    size_t outputSize;
    void* bufferIn;
    void* bufferOut;

    CLLib(string filename, string kernelName)
    {

        /* Get Platform and Device Info */
        ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
        ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices);


        /* Create OpenCL context */
        context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);

        /* Create Command Queue */
        command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);

        bool read = readFile(filename, &source);
        if(!read) throw "Failed to read a file";

        size_t source_size = source.length() + 1;
        char* source_str = new char[source_size];
        strcpy_s(source_str, source_size * sizeof(char), source.c_str());

        /* Create Kernel Program from the source */
        program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&source_str,
            (const size_t *)&source_size, &ret);


        /* Build Kernel Program */
        ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if (ret == CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE) {
            // Determine the size of the log
            size_t log_size;
            clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, NULL, &log_size);

            // Allocate memory for the log
            char *log = (char *) malloc(log_size);

            // Get the log
            clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, log_size, log, NULL);

            // Print the log
            printf("%s\n", log);
        }


        /* Create OpenCL Kernel */

        kernel = clCreateKernel(program, kernelName.c_str(), &ret);

        delete[] source_str;

    }


    void reinitDataContainers(size_t inputSize, size_t outputSize)
    {
        this->inputSize = inputSize;
        this->outputSize = outputSize;

        if(bufferIn){
            free(bufferIn);
        }
        if(bufferOut){
            free(bufferOut);
        }

        bufferIn = malloc(inputSize);
        bufferOut = malloc(outputSize);

        if(memobjInput){
            ret = clReleaseMemObject(memobjInput);
        }
        if(memobjOutput){
            ret = clReleaseMemObject(memobjOutput);
        }


        memobjInput = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, inputSize, 0, &ret);
        memobjOutput = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, outputSize, 0, &ret);

    }
    void build(size_t dimSize, size_t workGroups, size_t workItems)
    {
        this->workGroups = workGroups;
        this->workItems = workItems;
        this->dimSize = dimSize;

        clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, memobjInput, CL_TRUE, 0, inputSize, bufferIn, 0, NULL, NULL);

        /* Set OpenCL Kernel Parameters */
        ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&memobjInput);
        ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&memobjOutput);

    }

    void execute()
    {
        /* Execute OpenCL Kernel */
        ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, dimSize, 0, &workGroups, &workItems, 0, NULL, NULL);

        double curTime = Timer::getTimeNanoSeconds();
        clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, memobjOutput, CL_TRUE, 0, outputSize, bufferOut, 0, NULL, NULL);
        //println("delta: "+ toString(Timer::getTimeNanoSeconds() - curTime));
    }


    void release()
    {
        /* Finalization */
        ret = clFlush(command_queue);
        ret = clFinish(command_queue);
        ret = clReleaseKernel(kernel);
        ret = clReleaseProgram(program);
        ret = clReleaseMemObject(memobjInput);
        ret = clReleaseMemObject(memobjOutput);
        ret = clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
        ret = clReleaseContext(context);

        free(bufferIn);
        free(bufferOut);
    }
}
```

Comment: This 8ms probably include kernel execution time and data read. Do you call `clFinish` before reading data back? I'm assuming reading data is a blocking call and `clFinish` in between would block until kernel execution is done which would give you the real kernel and data read time. If you could post a host code that would be helpful to figure out.

Comment: @doqtor I added the code

Comment: @doqtor I also measured the kernel execution time without buffer reading, it's real fast

Comment: Look at the OpenCL Bandwidth Test  for OpenCL from Nvidia https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl. This will give a benchmark to compare against  and some sample code that works and measures accurately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comment you probably measure kernel execution and reading data together and think that reading data takes long time. Below is how you should measure it properly:

```
void execute()
{
    /* Execute OpenCL Kernel */
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, dimSize, 0, &workGroups, &workItems, 0, NULL, NULL);
    clFinish(command_queue);
    double curTime = Timer::getTimeNanoSeconds();
    clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, memobjOutput, CL_TRUE, 0, outputSize, bufferOut, 0, NULL, NULL);
    double curTime2 = Timer::getTimeNanoSeconds();
    println("delta kernel: "+ toString(curTime - curTime2));
    println("delta data read: "+ toString(Timer::getTimeNanoSeconds() - curTime2));
}
```

Normally `clFinish` just before blocking read is redundant but it helps to get the correct kernel timings.

Comment: Now I got it, really messed up with the clFinish thing, thanks

Comment: Just a note: For a real application, remove all the clFinish(), just call them when you really need the data. In order to improve parallel CPU/GPU